# Nodejs express headers on the websocket scope

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io

I've got a node.js + express + socket.io app.

i want to save the request headers in the socket, to use later.

```
io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {

  socket.headers = {};

  app.get('*', function (req, res) {

    //fetch headers
    socket.headers.ua = req.headers['user-agent'];  

    res.sendfile(__dirname + '/index.html');

  });
  ....etc
```

but because i am in the app scope, socket isnt defined. I always get confused with the in and out scope.
i cannot app.get() it, because if another browser connects, the app will be changed, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're doing it wrong. Every socket has a `handshake` object with it which contains request headers, domain, host, date etc. If you still want to fetch headers information then do this:

```
io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket) {
  console.log(socket.handshake); //This would print handshake object in JSON format
  // to get req-header, do this
  socket.head = socket.handshake.headers['user-agent'];
});
```

And you can use this property later in some event like:

```
socket.on('EventName',function(data){
  console.log(socket.head);
});
```

Comment: Perfect! Indeed i was looking on the wrong place. I was so stuck on my Express connection that i didn't think of the fast that the socket might have it too! Thanks!